# connect ionic3 with socket clusters websocket or socket.io

Tags: angular, websocket, ionic3, socketcluster

I have working code with `cordova` but want to transform it to `ionic3` but unable to find any reference. I don't want to use Fire-base i have my own socket server.  `I know i could have added some of my code to it but i am only able to find of ionic 2`#

Answer (score 0):

You can use some Angularjs websocket wrapper, like [this](https://github.com/afrad/angular2-websocket).

```
import {$WebSocket} from 'angular2-websocket/angular2-websocket'
const ws = new $WebSocket("url");
ws.send(event);
```

Comment: thanks for replay sir but 
1.  I am using socket cluster
2. Angular 4 
or it will be great if WS with angular 4 instead of angular 2